# MathJax is not defined angular 4

Tags: angular, mathjax

I have run command npm install mathjax and npm install --save @types/mathjax

and added reference of mathjax.js in angular-cli.json

```
"../node_modules/mathjax/mathjax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML"
```

. I have created directive

```
import { Directive, Input, OnChanges, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
    declare var MathJax: any;

    @Directive({
    selector: '[MathJax]'
    })
    export class MathJaxDirective implements OnChanges {

        @Input('MathJax') private value: string;

        constructor(private element: ElementRef) {

    }

    ngOnChanges() {

        // console.log('- onChange -');
        // console.log(this.value);

        this.element.nativeElement.innerHTML = this.value;
        MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset", MathJax.Hub, this.element.nativeElement]);
        }

    }
```

this showing error Mathjax **ReferenceError: MathJax is not defined**

I have added **mathjax** in types of tsconfig.app.json

```
        {
      "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
      "compilerOptions": {
        "outDir": "../out-tsc/app",
        "baseUrl": "./",
        "module": "es2015",
        "types": [
          "mathjax"
        ]
      },
      "exclude": [
        "test.ts",
        "**/*.spec.ts"
      ]
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting MathJax 'undefined' because it is not loaded to your browser.
Either add

```
 <script type="text/javascript" async
  src="https://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS_CHTML">
</script>
```

Or Replace

```
declare var MathJax: any;
```

with

```
import { MathJax } from 'mathjax';
```

And add "mathjax" to the types array in src/tsconfig.app.json.

Comment: i tried using import {MathJax } from 'mathjax' it showing error -e:/...//node_modules/@types/mathjax/index.d.ts' is not a module

Comment: Have you added "mathjax" to the types array in src/tsconfig.app.json ?

Comment: i used import 'mathjax' . error is gone but still not working

Comment: Hi, I am facing the same issue. Were you able to solve it ?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone facing the same problem:
Based on this demo https://mathjax.github.io/MathJax-demos-web/input-tex2chtml.html.html you could change your code like this:

```js
ngOnChanges() {
  this.target = this.element.nativeElement;
  MathJax.texReset();
  const options = MathJax.getMetricsFor(this.target);
  const node = await MathJax.tex2chtmlPromise(this.value, options);
  this.target.appendChild(node);
  MathJax.startup.document.clear();
  MathJax.startup.document.updateDocument();
}
```

As @Sundar mentioned, make sure to include the mathjax script tag in your `index.html` which now looks something like this:

```html
<script id="MathJax-script" async
  src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mathjax@3/es5/tex-mml-chtml.js">
</script>
```